# Compare value of one field in one table to the total sum of one column in another table

Tags: sql, db2

I'm having trouble with executing a query to compare where the value of a column in one table is not equal to the sum of another column in a different table.  Below is the query I have been trying to execute:

```
select id.invoice_no,sum(id.bank_charges),
from db2apps.invoice_d id
inner join db2apps.invoice_h ih on (id.invoice_no = ih.invoice_no)
group by id.invoice_no
having coalesce(sum(id.bank_charges), 0) != ih.tax_value
with ur;
```

I tried with joining on the tables, the group by having format, etc and have had no luck.  I really want to select id.invoice_no, ih.tax_value, and sum(id.bank_charges) in the result set, and also grab the data where the sum(id.bank_charges) is not equal to the value of ih.tax_value.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us an example of how it should be the output ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this solves your problem:

```
select ih.invoice_no, ih.tax_value, sum(id.bank_charges)
from db2apps.invoice_h ih left join
     db2apps.invoice_d id
     on id.invoice_no = ih.invoice_no
group by ih.invoice_no, ih.tax_value
having coalesce(sum(id.bank_charges), 0) <> ih.tax_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most logical way is probably to SUM the invoice detail first.

```
SELECT  IH.INVOICE_NO
,       IH.TAX_VALUE
FROM
    DB2APPS.INVOICE_H IH 
JOIN
(   SELECT  INVOICE_NO
    ,       COALESCE(SUM(BANK_CHARGES),0) AS BANK_CHARGES
    FROM
        DB2APPS.INVOICE_D
    GROUP BY
             INVOICE_NO
) ID
ON
    ID.INVOICE_NO = IH.INVOICE_NO
WHERE
    ID.BANK_CHARGE <> IH.TAX_VALUE
```

Generally, you never *need* to use `HAVING` in SQL and often your code will be clearer and easier to follow if you do avoid using it (even if it it sometimes a bit longer).

P.S. you can remove the `COALESCE` if `BANK_CHARGES` is NOT NULL.